# How exactly it is stored in memory – nesting is confusing

Tags: c#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

In the above link “Node” Class has “Node” as its data member.
How exactly it is stored in the memory? Because when it creates the memory structure for “Node” one of the member has “Node” memory structure. For some reason I am not able to understand the inner working of how it is interpreted in the program and compiled by the compiler?

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)  What problem do you face that an answer too would solve?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your trouble is stemming from from the fact that you intuitively think that the data member Node (or rather the memory allocated for it) is contained within the original Node.

Key to understanding is that the Node member is actually a reference - it could be null.  So the memory that is used for storing the data that makes up the node could be anywhere.  The Node member is essentially a pointer.

.NET and modern languages tend to obscure this kind of thing so that programmers don't need to think about it.  If I were you I would consider finding a quality C text and carefully reading the chapter on pointers.

Answer (score 1):

the `Node` member there isn't "embedded" or "nested" as you call it.

it is simply a *reference* to another node.  If you were doing C or C++, it would conceptually be a pointer to anohter node.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class Node
{
    private Node next;
    private T data;

    ...
}
```

The private field `next` stores a reference to an object of type `Node`.  The object that it references will be somewhere else in memory.